# eth_getProof for event logs?

Tags: json-rpc, light-clients, merkle-patricia-tries, proof

### Problem Brief

Hi, I've been looking for ways to prove to a light client that a log did get emitted on ethereum. I stumbled upon the eth_getProof RPC, but it's for getting the merkle proof for account state.

### Question

1. Why is there no similar RPC for getting proofs for the receipt or transaction tree?
2. If there is really no such RPC, does it mean I definitely need to run a full node in order to generate such proofs? Is there any third-party services that provide this functionality?